# Testing a pure C code on Xcode?

Tags: c, xcode

I am trying to use the latest Xcode to simulate some C code, that has nothing to do with iPhone, only test some data manipulation on C functions, and print results to see it working.

I have started a new playground in Xcode , for iOS , but it gives error when you try to write some C code  ( `char me[]= "this is me" ;`  )

How can i do it anyway ?
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The playground is for swift, not C, hence the errors.

You can develop C programs using Xcode, but you want to target OSX, probably using the command line project template.

Start by writing `main()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**:  In order to call a function outside of `main()` you must *declare* it before it is referenced:

```
// Forward declaration of function
static void printit(const char *message);

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    printit("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
}

static void printit(const char *message)
{
    fwrite(message, 1, strlen(message), stdout);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot i just saw that, but you cant really set regular C functions , if i write a new function outside the main :    int  printit(){}  , and I try to call it from the main with printit(); I get error. this not seems like a C code.

Comment: @Curnelious OK, let me show you how to solve *that* particular error, but it will have to stop there I'm afraid...

Comment: don't bother if its so hard, seems like you have to declare it in C99 .

Comment: @Curnelious You've *always* had to declare it.  It's the same in C++ and many other languages.

Comment: no you don't always. Embedded C for hardware is not working like that. but thanks a lot for your answer.